# is stateless non-const value usable in a constant expression?

Tags: c++, constants, c++17, stateless

The stackexchange page:

> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/386602/any-need-for-constexpr-in-tag-values

contains the following statement:

> Namespace-level variables and static class variables can
>    only be used in a constexpr context if they themselves are
>    constexpr, the exception being classes and structs that
>    are entirely empty.

which implies, IIUC, the following "stateless-are-constexpr"
statement:

> a non-const variable of an entirely empty
>    (a.k.a. stateless) type is usable in a constant
>    expression.

However, even after seriously studying:

> 7.7 Constant expressions [expr.const]

from:

> http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/n4800.pdf

I can't see anyplace in section 7.7 that says or implies
what the above "stateless-are-constexpr" statement says.  It
mentions literal values but nothing about non-const
stateless values.

Could somebody please explain how the above  statement can be
inferred from what the n4800 section 7.7 or any other
section says?

Note, I can logically infer it myself from the fact that a
stateless variable can only have one value, just as the
literal, 1, can have only one value, but I can't infer that
from n4800 section 7.7 without some help.

More specifically, using code from the stackexchange page,
how does n4800 say that:

```
struct A {};
A a_global; 
constexpr auto a_cexpr = a_global;
```

will compile?  Furthermore, does compilability of the above
code show that a_global is usable in a constant expression?
If not, what is a proper way to show this?

Note, 2 compilers I've used do compile it, but I'd like some
assurances that they are correct.

TIA.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#10?

Comment: Given `struct B{ B(const B&){ std::cout << 42; } };`, `B` wouldn't be usable as a `constexpr`.

Comment: Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit for the basic.types#10 link.  The important part is the Note where it says there's no guarantee that a literal "will be usable in a constant expression".  I conclude that it's a matter of which compiler you're using whether or not a stateless types is usable in a constant expression.

Comment: @user1681377 That's where `[expr.const]` comes in, isn't it? I thought maybe you were missing the definition of "literal type".

Answer (score 0):

You can pass references to non-`constexpr` data to `constexpr` functions; if you never use the reference, there is no problem.

```
struct A{
  int x=7;
  A()=default;
  A(int in):x(in){}
  constexpr A(A const&) {};
};

A a=rand();
constexpr auto b = a;
int main(){}
```

Your empty type just makes the copy ctor constexpr and never reads anything.  Copy ctor copies nothing, so doesn't care what its input is.